# Easy question which doesn't make sense to me!

Tags: contest-math, arithmetic

So I have to solve this problem:

Problem 7. In a basin of saltwater of $60\,\text{m}^3$ the amount of water sank by means of evaporation from $95.5\%$ to $93\%.$  How much saltwater remains in the basin?

I calculated $60 \times 0.045 = 2.7$
So therefore $60-2.7 = 57.3$

And $60 \times 0.07 = 4.7$

So there should be $52.6\, \text{m}^3$ still in the basin and the water sank by $2.$

Makes sense for me. The answer however is $28.57$ according to the solutions, what am I doing wrong or rather think wrong?

Comment: It's hard to follow what you were thinking - perhaps you could explain each step of your calculation (why did you multiply 60 by 0.045? Why did you subtract that from 60? What does the number 57.3 represent? Etc.)

Comment: why did you multiply 60 by 0.045

To get to 95,5%

Why did you subtract that from 60
That should be the amount still in the basin at 95,5%

What does the number 57.3 represent?
The amount still in the basin

Comment: Great. Continue to explain your entire solution that way.

Comment: Can you clarify what those two percentages are referring to? is it the percentage of the total  basin  volume ($60m^3$ ?) or of something else?

Comment: Not percentages, 2 m^2.
But I still don't get why the solution should be 38,57

Comment: If I interpret the percentages as giving the _concentration_ of water in the saltwater solution, I get 38.57. Try the problem this way and comment again if you'd like me to write up a full solution.

Comment: But if the whole  basin has 60, how can over 90% be 38,57, which is around 60%

Comment: Try to interpret the percentage as the percentage of the liquid, not as a percentage of the whole basin.